# Structuring a multi-view (multiple pages) Knockout.js app

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I've been working with Knockout.js for a couple of weeks now doing examples and other tutorials, but I'm still trying to figure out how to structure everything on the app I'm working on. It's a simple school backend app that keeps a list of all the classes, grades, teachers, attendance, and students. It has multiple pages:

- list of all the clases (where you can add/edit/remove classes)
- each class has a list its students (where you can add/edit/remove students)
- each student has a list of his/her attendance and grades
- teachers page
- school subjects page
- and others ...

How do I go about structuring this app? I've already started on the 'classes' page by creating a Class Model:

```
function Class(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.id = data.id;
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
  self.students = data.students;
  self.attendance = data.attendance;
}
```

... and a Class ViewModel that loads the initial content (list of classes). It also contains a function to add, edit and remove classes.

```
function ClassViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.classes = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(classArr, function(eachClass) {
    return new Class(eachClass);
  }));

  [...]
}
```

So do I continue doing a separate Model and ViewModel for each major part of the app (students, teachers, subjects, etc) and bind them separately on their own pages? And if I go this route, how do I go about sharing functions between ViewModels without having the same function added to each of them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have created a convention over configuration library for KO called Knockout.BindingConventions.

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions/wiki

Install using nuget

```
Install-Package Knockout.BindingConventions
```

One feature of that library is its template convention, basically it understands that a viewmodel named *ClassViewModel* should be connected to a template (View) called *ClassView*

http://jsfiddle.net/xJL7u/

I've also created a template bootstrapper that utilizes above library
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap/wiki

Install using nuget

```
Install-Package Knockout.Bootstrap
```

With these two libraries combined you can structure your application like this on server (Using your ClassViewModel as example)

```
app
    Class
        ClassViewModel.js
        OtherViewModel.js
    Shared
        DatePickerViewModel.js
views
    Class
        ClassView.htm
        OtherView.htm
    Shared
        DatePickerView.htm
```

Fully working MVC4 demo here
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap.Demo